# Check if a reacting user has a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I was making a platform for a suggestion channel. The idea was that there is a voting, and when it reaches a such cap, it auto accepts or rejects. I was also making staff can approve or reject. Well, i had a problem in this.

An image of this platform (I censored out the nicknames):
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yJwh.png)

When it reaches the approve cap (10 white check marks), it is supposed to delete the embed and post a new one meaning that the suggestion is approved.

Reproducible sample of code:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", function (messageReaction, member) {
if (member.bot) return;
    if (messageReaction.message.channel.id == "516263179446124555") {
     if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "✅") {
      if (messageReaction.count >= 10) {
        messageReaction.message.channel.send("", {embed: {
          title: "Suggestion Approved",
          description: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].title + "\n" + messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description,
          author: {
            name: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name,
            icon_url: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.iconURL
          },
          color: 3394611,
          footer: {
            text: "Why: The message got 10 ✅ reactions."
          }
        }})
      }
      messageReaction.message.delete();
    }
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "516258169035554817") {
      if (messageReaction.count >= 8) {
        messageReaction.message.channel.send("", {embed: {
          title: "Suggestion sent to Staff",
          description: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].title + "\n" + messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description,
          author: {
            name: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name,
            icon_url: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.iconURL
          },
          color: 16764006,
          footer: {
            text: "Why: The message got 8 <:neutral:516258169035554817> reactions."
          }
        }})
      }

messageReaction.message.guild.channels.get("517331518843125760").send("", {embed: {
        title: "Suggestion to check",
        description: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].title + "\n" + messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description,
        author: {
          name: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name,
          icon_url: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.iconURL
        },
        color: 16764006,
        footer: {
          text: "Approving/disapproving this won't change the embed in <#516263179446124555>."
        }
      }})
      messageReaction.message.delete();
    }
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "516258587845328906") {
      if (messageReaction.count >= 7) {
        messageReaction.message.channel.send("", {embed: {
          title: "Suggestion Rejected",
          description: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].title + "\n" + messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description,
          author: {
            name: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name,
            icon_url: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.iconURL
          },
          color: 16724736,
          footer: {
            text: "Why: The message got 7 <:bad:516258587845328906> reactions."
          }
        }})
      }
    }
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "☑") {
      var staffMemberReacted = false;
      messageReaction.message.guild.members.forEach(function(GuildMember) {
        if (messageReaction.users.keyArray().includes(GuildMember.user) && (GuildMember.roles.has("501752627709870080") || GuildMember.roles.has("493436150019784704"))) {
          staffMemberReacted = true;
        }
      })
        console.log("reached manapprove")
      if (staffMemberReacted) {
        messageReaction.message.channel.send("", {embed: {
          title: "Suggestion Approved",
          description: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].title + "\n" + messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description,
          author: {
            name: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name,
            icon_url: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.iconURL
          },
          color: 3394611,
          footer: {
            text: "Why: A owner or co-owner manually approved it."
          }
        }})
        messageReaction.message.delete();
      }
    }
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "517327626373824522") {
      var staffMemberReacted = false;
      messageReaction.message.guild.members.forEach(function(GuildMember) {
        if (messageReaction.users.keyArray().includes(GuildMember.user) && (GuildMember.id || GuildMember.roles.find)) {
          staffMemberReacted = true;
        }
      })

      if (staffMemberReacted) {
        messageReaction.message.channel.send("", {embed: {
          title: "Suggestion Rejected",
          description: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].title + "\n" + messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description,
          author: {
            name: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.name,
            icon_url: messageReaction.message.embeds[0].author.iconURL
          },
          color: 16724736,
          footer: {
            text: "Why: A owner or co-owner manually rejected it."
          }
        }})
        messageReaction.message.delete();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

When adding a console.log of it reaching, heroku logs don't put out anything. I was looking for the problem for over a hour.

Comment: `if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "✅") {
      if (messageReaction.count >= 10) {` will run if there are 9 ❎ and then someone does a ✅

Answer (score 0):

Please never do this.

Discord.js has a guide on what to do in this situation https://discordjs.guide/#/popular-topics/reactions?id=awaiting-reactions

I would follow their example and use [`message.awaitReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) To sum it up, use the filter to set the possible reactions you will consider, makes everything much easier.

This is from that link.

```
message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
        }
        else {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs down.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
        message.reply('you didn\'t react with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
```

Comment: Heroku is pretty unstable, so whenever the awaitReactions is running, the bot may crash due to unhandled "error" event (heroku side). I need something to be compatible with it